# Detect contour from point grid

Tags: square-grid

Suppose we have a grid of points (which can also be very dense 10000x10000) like the one in the figure in which the points are marked with two different colors.
[image]

What is the best algorithm from a performance point of view that allows me to reconstruct the outline of the red dots connecting the points of the grid itself? Here is the result I expect.

[image]
In the figure the contour is continuous, but in reality I'm also fine with finding a stepped contour that connects the border points between the red and blue ones. In general the region of red points is always connected but may not be convex. The algorithm will be added inside a simulation routine, so it should be as fast as possible.

Comment: Is there a scalar value associated to every grid point (positive on the blue points, negative on the red) ?

Comment: A possible approach consider the 4-adjacency graph of your grid (you don't have to explicitly generate it) and perform any visit (e.g., BFS) from an arbitrary red point to discover the connected component of the red points. Keep only the points with at least one blue neighbor.

Comment: @Steven: how does that define a smooth outline ?

Comment: It doesn't but the question says that a stepped countour is also fine.

Comment: @Steven: so how does that define a stepped outline ?

Comment: Except for "thin" shapes, any selected red dot has exactly two selected red neighbors in the 8-adjacency graph. This defines a cycle, i.e., closed outine. "Thin" shapes can be handled by first creating a $3\times$denser grid (replace each point by, e.g., a $3\times 3$ grid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Marching squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) might be the simplest. Imagine that the red points are samples with value -1 and the blue points are samples with value 1, then look for a line with value 0.

This algorithm is optimal, in that you have to visit each cell at least once, and this visits each cell once.

Just for completeness, if you did want a smoother outline, there are some options. One option is to "blur" the image first (either explicitly or implicitly), which would give the marching squares algorithm a little more information to go on.

Another option is to smooth the contour as a post-pass, but to do that, you need an appropriate representation and an appropriate definition of "smooth".

To help you in your search for that step, cartographers refer to producing lower-resolution versions of contours "[generalising](http://www.mountaincartography.org/activities/workshops/berchtesgaden_germany/presentations/Tutic_Stanfel_Jogun_Automatization_Cartographic_Generalisation.pdf)", which is an overloaded word. In meteorology and spatial data science, contour lines on maps are also known as "isopleths".